# Android App crash reason

Tags: java, android, eclipse, crash, adb

I am new with eclipse I don't know how to find the why app is crashing at start. I am compiling cocos2d-x app that I used first build_native.sh file to compile, then I used Eclipse for testing on device when I tested it says unfortunately your app crashed

Here is the log:

```
04-18 12:09:48.158: D/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.utils.MAPLog.PII(6012): Extracting verison incremental:<obscured>
04-18 12:09:48.168: D/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.utils.MAPLog.PII(6012): Incremental version '%s' was in invalid format.:<obscured>
04-18 12:09:48.168: I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.PackageIntentReceiver(6012): Package Intent Received. Clearing Service Data. action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED
04-18 12:09:48.168: I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.ThirdPartyServiceHelper(6012): Clearing Highest Versioned Service
04-18 12:09:48.829: W/dalvikvm(6012): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/goldcoin/letitredfree/MainActivity;
04-18 12:09:48.829: W/dalvikvm(6012): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/goldcoin/letitredfree/MainActivity;)
04-18 12:09:48.829: W/dalvikvm(6012): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bf41f8)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1026)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1883)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1285]:   170 cannot locate '__isnanf'...
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at com.goldcoin.letitredfree.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:127)
04-18 12:09:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     ... 15 more
```

Comment: please add your code.

Comment: Why are you using eclipse? Use android studio